# MS ACCESS - How to filter a splitform's datasheet by a multiple combobox values

Tags: ms-access, filter, combobox, multiple-value, datasheet

I have a splitform with some txtboxes and 1 combobox.
The combobox is related to the same form's query (qryPurchase) and it shows 3 columns of the query fields:

```
ID_purchase, Purchase_Type, Date_Purchase
```

In the query there other fields like `Purchase_Item`, `Quantity` and so on, but there are only 2 kind of Purchase_Type values, sell and borrow.
Different `Purchase_Item` can have the same `ID_purchase` and `Date_Purchase` like an invoice.

example of the combobox list:

```
ID_purchase, Purchase_Type, Date_Purchase
1, sell, 08/01/2020
1, sell, 09/01/2020
1, borrow, 09/01/2020
2, sell, 10/01/2020
2, borrow, 11/01/2020
```

When i choose a row from the dropdown menu of the combobox, i want that it has to filter the splitform's datasheet below by the combobox's row values in order to get a datasheet filtered list of all ID_purchase and Purchase_Type and Date_Purchase that match with the combobox row values.

like in the list above, if i choose the first row, the datasheet below shows 2 records.

I tried to achive that like this:

```
Private Sub fltDocCombo_AfterUpdate()

Me.Form.Filter = "[ID_purchase] =" & Me.fltDocCombo.Column(0) _
& " AND [Purchase_Type] = " & "'" & Me.fltDocCombo.Column(1) & "'" _
& " AND [Date_Purchase] = " & "#" & Me.fltDocCombo.Column(2) & "#"

Me.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
Me.Form.Filter = ""
Me.Form.FilterOn = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Me.Form.Filter = ""
Me.Form.FilterOn = False
End Sub
```

This sometimes works sometimes not, it seems that the `Me.Form.Filter` value is locked on the first ID_purchase of the list..

like in the example above:

```
ID_purchase, Purchase_Type, Date_Purchase
1, sell, 08/01/2020
1, sell, 09/01/2020
1, borrow, 09/01/2020
2, sell, 10/01/2020
2, borrow, 11/01/2020
```

If i try to choose the 2nd row, the filter applied is the first row values..
But not everytime..

Sometimes it seems that the filter of `Date_Purchase` doesn't filter nothing..

I thought to apply the filters sequantially like ID_purchase first,
Purchase_Type second and Date the last one,
but when it applies the second filter it cancel the first one and so on..

In this case i don't know how to add another filter to an existing one..

help..

Answer (score 0):

Solved..

the problem was the `Date_Purchase` Date format..

MS-ACCESS was installed for my local language and date format (dd/mm/yyyy)
but in VBA the Date default format is always mm/dd/yyyy

so i modified the `Me.Form.Filter` value like this:

```
Me.Form.Filter = "[ID_turnin_temploan] =" & Me.fltDocCombo.Column(0) _
& " AND [Posizione] = " & "'" & Me.fltDocCombo.Column(1) & "'" _
& " AND [Data_turnin_temploan] = " & "#" & Format(Me.fltDocCombo.Column(2), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
```

and now it works!